# Different read-more link for each custom post type

Tags: custom-post-types, genesis-theme-framework, read-more

Trying to make a custom 'read more' link for different custom post types.

Tried this code but does not work as expected. Fairly certain the if/else logic is amiss.

Using a Genesis theme if that makes a difference.

```
function excerpt_read_more_link($output) {
    global $post;
    if ($post->post_type = 'speaker')
      {
        $output .= '<p><a class="speaker-more-link" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">View Speaker Profile</a></p>';  
        }

    elseif ($post->post_type = 'resources')
      {
        $output .= '<p><a class="speaker-more-link" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">More Resource Content</a></p>';  
        }

    else
        $read_more_text = 'Read more';
    return $output . '<a class="more-link" href="'. get_permalink($post->ID) . '">'.$read_more_text.'</a>';
}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'excerpt_read_more_link');
```

Comment: review http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.comparison.php

Comment: `=` set the value. `==` is a comparison operator and is what you need instead, unless you want to check type as well (`===`). This is a pure PHP problem and as such is off-topic here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No idea if this makes a difference, and don't know about the Genesis either but give it a shot

```
function excerpt_read_more_link($output) {
global $post;

if ( 'speaker' == get_post_type() ) { $output .= '<p><a class="speaker-more-link" href="'. get_permalink() . '">View Speaker Profile</a></p>'; }
elseif ( 'resources' == get_post_type() ) { $output .= '<p><a class="speaker-more-link" href="'. get_permalink() . '">More Resource Content</a></p>'; }
else { $output . '<a class="more-link" href="'. get_permalink() . '">Read more</a>'; }

return $output;
```

}
add_filter('the_excerpt', 'excerpt_read_more_link');

edit: and for the record, I don't know, for me the if/else logic seems solid. Not sure though, haven't really used any custom post types and it's really late and I'm half asleep :)

edit2: updated code.

Comment: Hello Jimi,

Your code gets me oh so very close.

For speaker archives the 'read more' does appears as a delighful button but does not include the 'view speaker profile' text: http://www.toastmasters-d58.org/topics/storytelling/?post_type=speakers&orderby=rand  

What's really quite the puzzle is the 'resources' archives. The button appears with the custom 'More Resource Content' but there's an extra little sub-button. Cannot figure out where this is coming from: http://www.toastmasters-d58.org/resources/

Comment: Well now that I look at the code, it doesn't really make any sense. The way you define $output and then return that + the link with permalink and read_more_text. Give me a second. edit: there we go, I think it could now work, at least better.

Comment: Happy happy joy joy @jimihenrik. Thanks so much for your time and talent getting this solved. Also can now easily add additional custom 'read more' text links for additional custom post types. Again thanks.

Comment: No problem mate. Glad we got it solved!

Answer (score 0):

Try using `get_the_excerpt` instead of `the_excerpt` (it's not the same grammar as `the_content`)

As a sidenote, Genesis has ready-rolled functions to do what you want that don't use `the_excerpt`. You can find all of the below on the Studiopress website.

If you're using "Content Limit on the Content Archives section on the Genesis Settings page" then use this function:

```
//* Modify the Genesis content limit read more link
add_filter( 'get_the_content_more_link', 'sp_read_more_link' );
function sp_read_more_link() {
    return '... <a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">[Continue Reading]</a>';
}
```

When "using the WordPress More Tag to break a post on your site" use this:

```
//* Modify the WordPress read more link
add_filter( 'the_content_more_link', 'sp_read_more_link' );
function sp_read_more_link() {
    return '<a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">[Continue Reading]</a>';
}
```

If, however, you are using "Content Limit" in Genesis, then the StudioPress snippets provide [the following](http://my.studiopress.com/snippets/post-excerpts/#content-limit-more-link): "Code to modify the read more link when using the Content Limit on the Content Archives section on the Genesis Settings page:"

```
//* Modify the Genesis content limit read more link
add_filter( 'get_the_content_more_link', 'sp_read_more_link' );
function sp_read_more_link() {
    return '... <a class="more-link" href="' . get_permalink() . '">[Continue Reading]</a>';
}
```

Comment: Here's the Codex on `get_the_excerpt` - https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/get_the_excerpt

Comment: Hey Pat thanks for your answer. Site is setup with the content limit setting - not using 'read-more' tags.

The code does not display a 'read more' tag on either of the custom post types for 'speakers' or 'resources'. Unsure what I'm doing incorrectly.

http://www.toastmasters-d58.org/resources/

http://www.toastmasters-d58.org/topics/storytelling/?post_type=speakers&orderby=rand

Comment: For "Content Limit" there is another filter (as per the StudioPress snippets that you should check out. I've modified my answer above, and added the filter. Post back if it works for you.